# Raspberry pi libraries for servo controlling and debounce

Tags: raspberry-pi

For my project I'm using 6 servos, One rotates continuously and other 5 in required time delays. What is the best library to use for a timing critical application and I also want to use debounce,event callbacks.I came across 
*RPI.GPIO
*Servo Blaster
*PIGPIO
*RPIO.GPIO

libariers, RPI.GPIO uses software PWM so it is not suitable for timing critical applications. PIGPIO doesn't have a inbuilt debounce, RPIO.GPIO servo and pwm methods are not updated for the Raspberry Pi2 yet. What is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. For timing you could use sys.time for python timing functions, like current date, time delay, etc.

Also, de-bouncing you don't need a library for. You should be able to handle that yourself. What kind of actions are you debouncing? are you servos fidgeting when you supply power? If you're looking for precise movements, I believe stepper motors would be more suited to the task. Did this help?

Comment: I have to take the exact time that one object moves from place A to B, so when the servo is controlled by software PWM there rotation speed varies from time to time so the time changes.  When a light beam get obstructed I capture images so sometimes it capture multiple images, to stop that I want to use debounce

Comment: Set a time delay of like 100ms between the light triggering the camera. That should effectively debounce it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WiringPi. Out of curiosity, how are your servos hooked up? The Pi has a limited number of PWM pins. For my own implementation, I bought an adafruit raspberry pi SERVO hat which uses an i2c signal to control several PWM interfaces, the library they include for that is very easy to use though soldering the pins onto the board was a bit time consuming.

Comment: Libraries such as pigpio, servo blaster allows to use multiple PWMs